# how to configure MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) on Red hat linux 4

Tags: linux, redhat, email-server

how to configure MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) on Red hat linux 4

Comment: This should go to serverfault, and it could use some elaboration, for example: which MTA is wanted (any?) and what attempts have already been made to make it work...

Comment: Could you be more specific? Try installing sendmail.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/en-US/System_Administration_Guide_/Mail_Transport_Agent_MTA_Configuration.html) and [here](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/en-US/Reference_Guide/s1-email-mta.html).

Answer (score 0):

Afternoon,

First off, have a good read over this HOWTO http://howtoforge.com/exim-mysql-cyrus-imapd-horde-centos5.1, don't worry Centos is the community version of redhat enterprise server.

In order to change the MTA agent you use the Alternatives command

```
alternatives --config mta
```

the configuration of exim is not difficult but i cant remember it all at the moment.

Howtoforge.com should be able to help though.

Have fun.